# Return selected objects for MultiSelect DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have this DropDownListFor added to my (partial) View **_CreateUser.cshtml** as:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="createUserModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create A User</h4>
    </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="modal-body">

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Departments)
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(
                model => model.SelectedDepartmentIds,
                new SelectList(Model.DepartmentSelectList, "Value", "Text"),
                new {@class = "multiselect departments", multiple = "multiple"})
            </div>
        ...
```

Above partial view is declared in main View **Index.cshtml** and is shown as modal popup on click of 'Create' button

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create user", "Create", "Users", new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @href = "#createUserModal", @data_toggle="modal" })    
...    
@Html.Partial("_CreateUser", new UserViewModel()
             {   //Populating SelectList required for loading dropdownlist
                 DepartmentSelectList = modelFactory != null ? 
                                        modelFactory.Departments.Select(dept => new SelectListItem{Value = dept.Id.ToString(),Text = dept.Name}).ToList() 
                                        : null
             })
```

**UserViewModel.cs**

```
public IEnumerable<String> Departments { get; set; }
//Used purely for binding DropDownList
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DepartmentSelectList { get; set; } 
public string SelectedDepartmentIds { get; set; }
//Ideally, I want to populate selected items in this list
public IEnumerable<DepartmentModel> DepartmentModels { get; set; }
```

**UserController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserViewModel postedModel)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Incorrect - returns only first selected Id
            string selectedIds = postedModel.SelectedDepartmentIds;

            //Correct - returns correct selected Ids
            string selectedIds1 = ModelState["SelectedDepartmentId"].Value.AttemptedValue;
            ...
            ...
```

Two questions:

How can I retrieve all selected items from DropDownList as part of model property "SelectedDepartmentId"?  Do I need to use jQuery to update the ModalProperty at run-time?

Can I setup my View so as to bind Modal property "DepartmentModels" with DropDownList - It will help me to retrieve complete objects for selected items?
Currently, if I try to do that, I get this error:
{"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type '...DepartmentModel' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."}

Thank you!

Comment: _"How can I retrieve all selected items from DropDownList"_. You are using `DropDownListFor` which only allows selection of one item. Do you want to select multiple items?  A `<select>`control only posts back a single value, not all the properties of a complex object.

Comment: I am using jQuery to allow multiple selection as: $('.multiselect').multiselect();

Comment: In that case property `SelectedDepartmentIds` should probably be `string[]` (I'm not familiar with the plugin your using but `<select multiple>` typically returns an array of values)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after looking through various Google searches :-)

Below is the code that loads and returns selected objects correctly -

**Model:**

```
public class UserGroupViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GroupSelectList
    {
        get
        {
            List<Group> groups = new List<Group>
                {
                    new Group() {Id = 1, Name = "AA"},
                    new Group() {Id = 2, Name = "BB"},
                    new Group() {Id = 3, Name = "CC"}
                };
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> groupsSelectList = groups.Select(group => new SelectListItem                                                                          {   Text = group.Name, Value = group.Id.ToString(), Selected = group.Id == 2}).ToList();
            return groupsSelectList;
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Group")]
    public int[] SelectedGroupIds { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedGroupIds, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedGroupIds,
                                Model.GroupSelectList,
                                new { @class = "multiselect", multiple = "multiple" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedGroupIds)
    </div>
</div>
```

For showing some of the items as 'Selected' on form load, simply set the SelectListItem's  'Selected' property to true.

HTH.